# Difference of two files in linux

Tags: linux, redhat

I am getting difference of two files from commandline when I included same line in the test.sh it is shown error
Syntax `comm -2 -3 <(sort user_list.csv) <(sort full_user_list.csv) > uniq_list.csv'` . Error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 9: `comm -2 -3 <(sort user_list.csv) <(sort ull_user_list.csv) > uniq_list.csv'
```

Comment: please show how your script looks like. The syntax looks fine

Comment: even the single line of the above syntax in the test.sh is showing the same error. example test.sh contains `comm -2 -3 <(sort user_list.csv) <(sort full_user_list.csv) > uniq_list.csv`

Comment: Please [edit] your question with this info; do not add code in comments. See [ask] also for a better experience here.

Comment: If and how this syntax works depends on the actually used shell, it has pretty little to do with the OS in use, let alone the OS kernel.

Comment: try to remove last char '   comm -2 -3 <(sort user_list.csv) <(sort full_user_list.csv) > uniq_list.csv

Comment: Wait a second: Do you want to say that if you do that on the commandline it works, but when you put it into a shellscript it doesn't? I'd like to emphasize that IO redirection depends on the shell and if you start your shellscript with `#!/bin/sh` it is a different shell than the typical BASH you get as commandline!

Answer (score 3):

try so

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort user_list.csv) <(sort full_user_list.csv)> uniq_list.csv
```

I have tried, it works.
Seeking a difference with your version...
Check that beetween `<` and `(` no space. If I will add a space beetween `<` and `(` I have the same error.